# Setting the start screen for the UltraVNC Viewer

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, ultravnc

I have a dual-monitor setup for using the Viewer.

My problem is that the Viewer always gets displayed on screen 1 instead of screen 2 (as identified by Windows).

How can I direct the Viewer-Windows to start on the second screen?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the UltraVNC viewer supports it but the RealVNC Viewer has an option called Monitor, which allows you to specify the monitor you want to open the viewer on. In my case if I wanted to open the Viewer on my second display I would set the monitor option to \\.\DISPLAY2

The option is available in the EE & PE versions of the viewer.

You need to find out what how your displays are enumerated though. You may only have 2 monitors, but Windows might refer to them as \\.\DISPLAY3 and \\.\DISPLAY5. I don't know why that happens but it can.

Answer (score 1):

This is only useful for situations where you'll be using a .VNC file to access the server:

Create a .VNC file for the connection (you can do this while remoted in, it's easier than making one from scratch).  Edit the .VNC file in any text editor application and look for/add a line that says:

```
selected_screen=[value]
```

Adjust the value accordingly.  For me, my primary monitor was screen 2.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal tool for this kind of configuration -- and ton of other great tweaks for multimonitor setups -- is [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/), from RealTime Soft. Not free: single license is $39.

For example, here's I'd launch my VNC viewer on a 2nd screen:

First, you set the program:

[image: ultramon1]

Then you tell it where to launch:

[image]

and this is followed by even more options to set the resolution/color depth of the target monitor, and finally how and when you'd like to use the launch.

Should add that I'm not affiliated with this company in any way: just a long time user of their product.

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me

```
selected_screen=[value]
```

But this is working fine. Just move VNC window whenever you want, close it and it will remmember last position

```
SavePos=1
```